# In throwing 6n dice, what is the probability of getting each face n times? Use Stirling's formula to estimate this probability for a large n.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question is taken from *Probability Theory: A Concise Course* by Y. A. Rozanov.

My attempt at a solution is as a following:

I think of $6n$ dice rolls as $n$ groups of 6 rolls. The probability that one rolls each face at least once in six rolls is $\frac{5!}{6^5}$ because there are $6^6$ outcomes of rolling six dice considering order, and of those $6^6$ outcomes there are $6!$ ways of ordering 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, representing all the different ways you could have obtained one of each face of the dice. Since there are $n$ groups of six rolls, the probability is simply $(\frac{5!}{6^5})^n$.

What part of the above is incorrect?

Clearly, however, the above doesn't use Stirling's formula, and I've read the solution by Joseph Goodknight's publicly posted PDF of his own solutions, but I don't fully understand his solution on how to get $\frac{(6n!)}{(n!)^6}$ which leads to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue of the "false" solution is the decomposition into $n$ groups of $6$ rolls. For example, when $n=2$, it counts outcomes like $1,2,4,3,6,5,3,2,1,6,5,4$ where the first six and the last six rolls contain all the numbers from $1$ to $6$, but misses valid outcomes like $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6$.

To get the correct solution, we want to count the number of ways we can arrange a sequence of $n$ $1$s, $n$ $2$s, ..., and $n$ $6$s. This is $(6n)!/(n!)^6$ (there are $(6n)!$ ways to order $6n$ objects, but there are six groups of $n$ digits that are indistinguishable from each other). Dividing this by $6^{6n}$ (the total number of possible outcomes) gives the probability.

Comment: Thank you, your answer cleared it up!